# docker machine vs docker for mac

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have installed docker for mac on my machine. I have pulled a repo from the docker hub, the docker run command includes the docker-machine ip parameter for which I get an error, Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exist. Could someone elaborate the difference between docker machine and docker for mac.

Answer (score 11):

If you have Docker for Mac running on your machine, you don't need Docker Machine. Using Docker Machine (usually through [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/)) to run locally only if you have an older Mac version that isn't supported, which isn't the case here, or a Windows machine without Windows 10 pro.

The only other case you need Docker Machine is for controlling remote machines or setting up multiple nodes locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the machine first of all. Try running the following command from your terminal of choice:

`docker-machine create testmachine`

Comment: You don't need Docker Toolbox to run Docker on a Mac anymore, unless you have an old Mac. [Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac) works much better and is less fiddly.